# how to determine when rerunning makeglossaries?

Tags: glossaries

As for indices, also for glossaries 
latex creates a raw index/glossary, 
then an external sorting tool, makeindex or makeglossaries is run 
and another latex run includes the sorted index/glossary into tex. 
The problem is, that not only latex must be rerun 
to obtain correct results, 
but also sometimes makeindex.

For indices, the package imakeidx seems to provide a solution, 
which includes sorting into the latex run 
so no explicit run of makeindex is required. 
Question: how can this be used for glossaries also???

Thank  you for help!!!

Comment: The `glossaries` package has an `automake` option which automatically runs `makeindex`.

Comment: Hey, thank you Nicola. I finally found something in the documentation.

Comment: You write that it probably does not work for xindy. Why that? Somewhere you write this is a last resort as makeindex is run after each latex run. How can i find out whether I have to rerun latex after the makeindex run??

Answer (score 2):

The `automake` package option uses the shell escape to generate the external files. This is analogous to `imakeidx`'s automatic feature.

Addressing your comments:

> You write that it probably does not work for xindy. Why that?

The `automake` option can work with `xindy` if you have the unrestricted shell escape on, but not if the restricted mode is on (which is usually the default for most TeX distributions). `makeindex` is considered a trusted application and may be run through the shell escape in restricted mode, but `xindy` isn't on the trusted list so it requires the unrestricted shell escape. (This also applies to `imakeidx` with `xindy`.)

If you look at the `texmf.cnf` file, you should find the following comment:

```
% we'd like to allow:
% dvips - but external commands can be executed, need at least -R1.
% epspdf, ps2pdf, pstopdf - need to respect openout_any,
%   and gs -dSAFER must be used and check for shell injection with filenames.
% pygmentize - but is the filter feature insecure?
% ps4pdf - but it calls an unrestricted latex.
% rpdfcrop - maybe ok, but let's get experience with repstopdf first.
% texindy,xindy - but is the module feature insecure?
```

So `xindy` has been considered for inclusion on the trusted list, but there's a security query which has prevented its addition.

The other problem is that you must make sure you set the language and code page exactly as required by `xindy`. The `makeglossaries` script maps known `babel` language labels to the appropriate label expected by `xindy`. For example if you have

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
```

Then `makeglossaries` picks up the language label `ngerman` from the `.aux` file, but knows that it needs to map this to `-L german`. The `makeglossaries` script can pick up the `uft8` encoding, but it will additionally add `din5007` since no codepage has been specified in the document that includes `din5007` or `duden` or `braille`. The `automake` option doesn't have this level of sophistication and will simply try `-L ngerman -C utf8`, which won't work.

So if you want the above `ngerman` example to work with `automake`, it must be written as:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[automake,xindy={language=german,codepage={din5007-utf8}}]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name=foo,description={an example}}

\begin{document}
\gls{foo}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

If run in restricted mode this doesn't create the glossary file and the log file contains:

```
runsystem(xindy -I xindy -L german -M test -C din5007-utf8 -t test.glg 
-o test.gls test.glo)...disabled (restricted).
```

(where the document was called `test.tex`.) The shell escape must be enabled:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape test
```

The `automake` option is considered a last resort because it lacks the sophistication of the `makeglossaries` script:

- the LaTeX code doesn't map `babel` language labels to `xindy` labels;
- the LaTeX code doesn't know about special cases for particular languages (such as the requirement of the `german` module to include one of `din5007`, `duden` or `braille`);
- the `makeglossaries` script analyses the transcript files if something goes wrong and will try to give a more intelligible message since some of the messages (especially from `xindy`) are quite cryptic;
- the `makeglossaries` script can correct some problems. In particular it detects `makeindex`'s "multiple encaps" warning and will try to fix the problem.

These kinds of tasks are far easier and far more efficient to do with a scripting language, such as Perl, than attempting it with TeX.

> How can i find out whether I have to rerun latex after the makeindex
>   run??

You will always need to run LaTeX after `makeindex` as it's `makeindex` that creates the files read by `\printglossary` (or `\printglossaries`). This is the same as for `imakeidx`.

You may need an extra `makeindex`/`xindy` run if the page numbers change between builds. For example, the inclusion of a table of contents where the page numbering isn't reset at the start of the front matter, can cause the indexed page numbers to change. This problem also occurs with `imakeidx`.

Another case that requires the glossary files to be rebuilt is if an entry is only referenced by another entry in the glossary. The most common case is when the `see` key is used.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name=foo,description={an example}}
\newglossaryentry{bar}{name=bar,description={another 
example},see={foo}}

\begin{document}
\gls{bar}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The steps `latex`, `makeindex`, `latex` only include the `bar` entry

[image: image of document]

since the `foo` entry can't be indexed until it's processed when the glossary file is read. This means that another `makeindex` and `latex` run are required.

Alternatively, if you use the extension package `glossaries-extra`, it will search for the `see` key of all used entries at the end of the document and automatically index them if they haven't been used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name=foo,description={an example}}
\newglossaryentry{bar}{name=bar,description={another 
example},see={foo}}

\begin{document}
\gls{bar}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This means that only `latex`, `makeindex` and `latex` are required.

[image: image of document]